Angular 18 Migration: 'TypeError: res is not iterable' Error due to spread operator
I recently migrated my Angular project from version 9 to version 18. After the migration, I started encountering the following error:
ERROR TypeError: res is not iterable
    onEscalate details.component.ts:735
    RxJS 5
        next
        _next
        next
        next
        errorContext
core.mjs:7185:18
    Angular 2
        handleError
        next
    RxJS 6
    Angular 22
        emit
        onHandleError
        invoke
        run
        runOutsideAngular
        onHandleError
        handleError
        runTask
        invokeTask
        invoke
        0
    (Async: setTimeout handler)
        scheduleTask
        scheduleTask
        onScheduleTask
        scheduleTask
        onScheduleTask
        scheduleTask
        scheduleTask
        scheduleMacroTask
        scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone
        setNative
        name
    RxJS 9
        setTimeout
        reportUnhandledError
        handleUnhandledError
        next
        _next
        next
        next
        errorContext
        next
    Angular 3
    RxJS 6
    Angular 4
    RxJS 15
    Angular 26
    onSubmit escalation-assign.component.ts:130
    EscalationAssignComponent_Template_button_click_98_listener escalation-assign.component.html:171
    Angular 28
    EscalationAssignComponent_Template escalation-assign.component.html:171
    Angular 13
    onEscalate details.component.ts:695

I suspect that the res variable, which I expect to be an iterable object (like an array), might not be in the expected format, especially after the migration.

please share the HTML and TS code for details.component.ts, also an API response

In your tsconfig.json, in the compilerOptions.lib property, add DOM.iterable.
"lib": ["ES2022", "dom", "DOM.Iterable"]

Example :


This solution is not working in my case
